# PostgreSQL: Indexes on text_pattern_ops and Order by works properly separately but not in same SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgreSQL 9.3.4, I have a table Company composed of ~= 10 millions elements. I would like to retrieve the first 100K company for which the `naics` (Character Varying) match a prefix and order by `revenue` (Bigint)

This query retrieve the correct result (with a prefix '11'):

```
SELECT c.* FROM Company c WHERE c.naics LIKE '11%' ORDER BY c.revenue DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 100000
```

But I have some issue on the running time

Therefore, I created 3 Indexes:

```
- CREATE INDEX naics_pattern_text_revenue_limit_idx ON Company (naics text_pattern_ops, revenue DESC NULLS LAST)
- CREATE INDEX naics_pattern_text_idx ON Company (naics text_pattern_ops)
- CREATE INDEX naics_revenue_desc_idx ON Company (revenue DESC NULLS LAST)
```

But the previous query do not use the correct index: `naics_pattern_text_revenue_limit_idx` but `naics_revenue_desc_idx`, and do not use the index on `naics_revenue_desc_idx` ->

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT c.* FROM Company c WHERE c.naics LIKE '11%' ORDER BY revenue DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 100000
 Limit  (cost=340805.34..341055.34 rows=100000 width=346) (actual time=1313.882..1358.690 rows=100000 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=340805.34..341145.33 rows=135996 width=346) (actual time=1313.880..1349.020 rows=100000 loops=1)
    Sort Key: revenue
    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 44544kB
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on company c  (cost=2855.63..285508.50 rows=135996 width=346) (actual time=42.681..1074.971 rows=167464 loops=1)
          Filter: ((naics)::text ~~ '11%'::text)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 2539459
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on naics_pattern_text_idx  (cost=0.00..2821.63 rows=134520 width=0) (actual time=41.289..41.289 rows=167464 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (((naics)::text ~>=~ '11'::text) AND ((naics)::text ~<~ '12'::text))
Total runtime: 1417.166 ms
```

The most annoying part is that if I query:

```
SELECT c.* FROM Company c WHERE c.naics LIKE '11%' LIMIT 100000
```

runs in 567.184 ms (using `naics_pattern_text_idx`) and

```
SELECT c.* FROM Company c ORDER BY revenue DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 100000
```

runs in 249.558 ms (using `naics_revenue_desc_idx`).

So my questions:

- Is there any way to create an index on `naics` and `revenue` that postgreSQL will correctly takes into account ?
- I was under the impression that postgreSQL should be able to use the index on `revenue` on a smaller subset of Company (once it's filter by `naics`). Am I missing something ?

PS: we (almost) never insert new data in the Company table. We only want to optimize the `select` whatever the overhead cost for `update` and `insert` is.

Comment: Can you increase the work_mem high enough so planner won't resort to external_merge (say 64MB) and check then?

Comment: @JakubKania Thanks! That divided the running time by more than 2. Now postgre use a `top-N heapsort Memory`, which speed up the speed a lot. Though, I still wondering why my first multi column index is not being use by postgreSQL.

Comment: You're selecting top 100k rows from 167k candidates. The query planner probably just decided it will be faster to sort them this way. If you use a more reasonable limit (say 1k) it should act the way you want it to. You may also try to set up a conditional index if you will be using that WHERE clause more often.